# Is it possible to treat tasks with controllable processing time?

Tags: optaplanner

I am wondering if it's possible to treat scheduling problems with tasks with the following property using Optaplanner. Instead of have a fixed duration of 1 hour we have a 1 hour-man, i.e if there is two employees working on that task, it could be done in 1/2 hour.

Otherwise, what are the other solvers that could be used ?

Answer (score 0):

Model wise, the easy approach is to split up that 1 task into 2 smaller tasks that get individually assigned. (When they're both assigned to the same person, sequentially after each other, you can add a soft constraint to reward that.) The downside is that you have to decide in advance for each task into how many pieces they can be split up.

In reality, tasks are rarely arbitrary dividable. **Some parts of each task are atomic.** For example, taking out the garbage can is a do-or-do-not task. Taking it half the way out, or taking half of it out, and assigning someone else to do the rest, is not allowed because it will increase the time spent on it.

Some tasks need at least 2 persons to execution. For example, someone to hold the ladder while the other is standing on it. In the docs, see the auto delay to last pattern.

Alternatively to the simple model, you can also play with `nullable=true` and custom moves to allow multiple people to assign to the same tasks, but it's complicated. It can avoid having to tune the number of task pieces in advance too much. Once we support `@PlanningVariableCollection`, and do so fully, more and better options in this regard will become available.